# login POST API flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart, authentication, post

I have a problem with log in when credantials are invalid it still navigate to next screen

```dart
//CREATE FUNCITON TO CALL LOGIN POST API

Future<void> login() async {
  if (passController.text.isNotEmpty && emailController.text.isNotEmpty) {
    Map data = {'email': emailController.text, 'password': passController.text};

    String body = json.encode(data);

    http.Response response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('//here api'),
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
      body: body,
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200 ) {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const VerificationScreen()),
      );
    } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text("Invalid Credentials")));
    }
  } else {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(content: Text("Blank Field  Not Allowed")));
  }
}
```

How to make `"Invalid Credentials"` message appears when pass and email are not correct

Comment: Usually when login with invalid credentials takes place, the API sends back response containing this message. So just await a response and show it with snackbar.

Comment: `if(response.statusCode==200 || response.statusCode == 400)`  why you navigate when its `400` ?

Comment: @pmatatias no I do not want to navigate in 400

Comment: after you edit, based on your function above, it shoud navigate only when 200. 

so if its keep navigate eventhough wrong password, probably your backend accept even user submit invalid username and password

Comment: or maybe, there are another function in your code that navigate to the next screen after execute the login method.

Comment: Please give me api response.then i will try tyis issue.

Comment: Or try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/71885194/16434562